# How to draw 3d cylinder directed in x axis with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3d

How to draw cylinder directed in x axis?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1cm,0.4cm)}, y={(8mm, -3mm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}, line cap=round, line join=round]

%   % Main Axes
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[below left] {$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[above] {$z$};

    % Big Axis
    \draw[line cap=round, -latex, very thick] (-0.5,0,0) -- (10,0,0);

    \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=5.5]
    \draw[] (0,0)  circle (1);
    \end{scope}
    
    \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=8.5]
    \draw[] (0,0)  circle (1);
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

In the future, it should look like picture below. But for now I have a problem with drawing a transparent cylinder along the desired axis in 3d.

[image]

Comment: I believe this [example](https://tikz.dev/library-3d#sec-40.3) from the TikZ manual is somewhat related (there's a sine in it, too).

Comment: Where does the figure come from?

Comment: Are you interested by drawing a cylinder and then being able to change the point of view?  After all you need a figure that lives in 3d, so what you represent is dependent of the observer's position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a start for that cylinder: What's in the foreground needs to be drawn last.

The angle `125` for the point of that tangent on the circles is guessed. I'm sure there's a way to calculate that from the given coordinate system vectors `x`, `y` and `z`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x={(1cm,0.4cm)},
  y={(8mm, -3mm)},
  z={(0cm,1cm)},
  line cap=round,
  line join=round,
  radius=1,
  delta angle=-180,
  front/.style={canvas is yz plane at x=5.5},
  back/.style={canvas is yz plane at x=8.5},
]

% Main Axes
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[below left] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[above] {$z$};

% back gray arc
\draw[back, gray] (125:1) arc[start angle=125, delta angle=180];
% bix axis (through and behind cylinder)
\draw[line cap=round, -latex, very thick] {
  [front] (0,0)} -- (10,0,0);

% cylinder
\draw[fill=pink,fill opacity=.5] {
    [back]
      (125:1) arc[start angle=125]
  }{
    [front]
      -- (125+180:1) arc[end angle=125]
  } --cycle;
% front arc
\draw[front]      (125:1) arc[start angle=125];
% foreground axis
\draw[very thick, line cap=rect] (-0.5,0,0) -- (5.5,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use [3dtools](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools) to make cylinder.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=130,theta=70,psi=0},declare function={r=2;h=8;}] 
    \path[3d/record physical components] 
    (1,0,0) coordinate (ez') 
    (0,1,0) coordinate (ex') 
    (0,0,1) coordinate (ey');
    \begin{scope}[x={(ex')},y={(ey')},z={(ez')}]
        \pic{3d/frustum={r=r,R=r,h=h}};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[3d/hidden] (0,0,-r) -- (0,0,r) (0,0,0) -- (h,0,0) ;
    \draw[3d/hidden] (0,0,0) -- (0,r,0);
    \node[above left] (O) at  (0,0,0) {$ O $};
    \fill  (0,0,0) circle[radius = 1.5pt];
    \draw[3d/visible, - latex] (h,0,0) -- (h+ 3,0,0) node[above]{$x$};
    \draw[3d/visible, - latex] (0,0,r) -- (0,0,r+1) node[above]{$z$};
    \draw[3d/visible, - latex] (0,r,0) -- (0,r+1,0) node[above]{$y$};    
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's draw the figure as it is. All codes is run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/.

**Step 4.** *(will be added later)*

**Step 3.** Now come the cylinder along the X-axis, I just use `unitcylinder` of the module `three` with some geometric transformations.

[image]

```
import graph3;
unitsize(5mm,2cm,1cm);
size3(8cm);
currentprojection=orthographic(Z-Y,zoom=.9,center=true);

// the sin wave and its bounding box on the XY-plane
triple f(real t) {return (t,sin(t),0);}
real xmin=0, xmax=16pi;
path3 gf=graph(f,xmin,xmax,operator..);
picture pic;
draw(pic,gf,red+2pt);
triple A=(0,-1,0), u=(0,2,0),v=(xmax,0,0);
path3 b=plane(u,v,A);
draw(surface(b),yellow+opacity(.5));
draw(b,blue);
add(pic);

// The cylinder along the X-axis
real h=8pi;
surface cyl=shift(12pi,0,0)*scale(h,3,3)*rotate(-90,Y)*unitcylinder;
draw(cyl,pink+opacity(.4));
```

**Step 2.** from 2D to 3D, use the graph of

```
triple f(real t) {return (t,sin(t),0);}
```

[image]

```
unitsize(5mm,2cm,1cm);
size3(8cm);
import graph3;
triple f(real t) {return (t,sin(t),0);}
path3 gf=graph(f,0,16pi,operator..);
picture pic;
draw(pic,gf,red+2pt);
triple A=(0,-1,0), u=(0,2,0),v=(16pi,0,0);
path3 b=plane(u,v,A);
draw(surface(b),yellow+opacity(.5));
draw(b,blue);
add(pic);
```

**Step 1.** 2D version use the graph of

```
real f(real x) {return sin(x);}
```

[image]

```
unitsize(5mm,2cm);
size(8cm);
import graph;
// the function y=f(x)=sin(x);
real f(real x) {return sin(x);}
guide gf=graph(f,0,16pi,operator..);
picture pic;
draw(pic,gf,red+2pt);
filldraw(box(point(pic,SW),point(pic,NE)),yellow+white+opacity(.5),blue);
add(pic);

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```